# Parallel processing MODIS images in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, gdal

I have downloaded all the vegetation data from MODIS for Africa and now I am trying yo create mosaics from the images and save them as geo tif. I have no problem doing all this until I try to run it in parallels on a MacPro 6cores, 12 threads. The code runs but it uses only 1% of the cores availability and takes for ever to complete the processes.

I really need help, I have more than 70GB of MODIS granules I need to convert to a mosaic and if I don't use all the computer power I got in the lab this will take for ever.

Here is the code part of parallel processing:

There are two parts run in parallel, 1. to select the NDVI; 2. To create the mosaics, project them and save them as .tif.

```
# register the cluster with 10 cores 
registerDoParallel(cores=11)
miCluster<-makeCluster(11)
registerDoParallel(miCluster)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(11)

# 1.
# select the NDVI for each Africa Granule and put it in SdsList
sdsList <- foreach(k = 1:length(dateGranules), .packages=c("raster", "gdalUtils","foreach"))%dopar%{
  for(j in 1:1:length(dateGranules)){
    return(sapply(X=dateGranules[[j]], FUN=function(x){get_subdatasets(x)[1]}))
  }
}

2.
# Generate the Mosaic for Africa with NDVI as aoutput
foreach(j = 1:length(sdsList), .packages=c("raster", "gdalUtils", "foreach"))%dopar%{
    gdalwarp(srcfile=sdsList[[j]], t_srs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84   +no_defs",
      dstfile=file.path(dest, names[j]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use R at all, when you can do it in two lines, from the shell, with multi threading and faster by using the [GDAL utilities](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716125119/http://gdal.org:80/gdal_utilities.html)?

If I understand your question and code correctly you want to extract the NDVI subdataset from, presumably MOD13Q1, HDF5 containers, reproject to lat/lon, change filetype to GeoTiff and mosaic all the granules covering Africa to one large mosaic.

1. Build a [Virtual Raster Table](https://gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) containing all the NDVI subdatasets.

`gdalbuildvrt -sd 1 NDVI.vrt MOD13Q1.*.hdf`

Note the use of `-sd 1` which only takes the first subdataset from every HDF container.

2. Reproject and change format.

`gdalwarp gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84   +no_defs" -multi  NDVI.vrt NDVI-mosaic.tif`

Step one takes virtually no time since it only creates a metadata file containing information about the hierarchy of the HDF files and no actual processing is done. If you granules are adjacent, e.g. h15v05, h15v04, h14v05,..., they will be mosaiced correctly by their geolocation.

Step two is the actual reprojection and file format change. I tested this on my core2duo (3GHz) and reprojection of 20 MODIS granules took roughly 1.5 minutes. So even without multi-threading you should be a lot faster than in R.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I wanted to do. Once I recover from the flu I'll what you said in the shell. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Kersten, I did what you suggested but I get the following error that never passes 40% progress with any data set I have: 

0...10...20...30...40.ERROR 4: `HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13A3.A2005213.h20v08.005.2008069184257.2005-08-01.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_1km_VI:1 km monthly NDVI' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Comment: Do you get the same error with your R method? Does it occur whike building the VRT or while warping? Sounds like the dataset differs from the rest of the MODIS hdf containers or might even be corrupt.

Comment: The error does not happen in R. I even downloaded the files that seemed corrupted. I think is a gdal issues since I had to enable the hdf4 capability because the brew version only came with hdf5. What do you think?

Comment: Could well be a gdal issue, especially with HDFs. What dataset exactly are you using that it is delivered in HDF4? To my knowledge all the current collection 5 datasets are HDF5.

Comment: Here is an example of the data I am using: http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODIS_Composites/MOLT/MOD13A3.005/2000.07.01/MOD13A3.A2000183.h21v06.005.2006310225305.hdf

Comment: I also just tested the [file that gave you the error](http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODIS_Composites/MOLT/MOD13A3.005/2005.08.01/MOD13A3.A2005213.h20v08.005.2008069184257.hdf). It works fine with me - as long as it is named correctly and really present on your system it should work.

Comment: That's really weird! Now I am trying to reinstall gdal from scratch. Are you on Linux or OSX?

Comment: when I used godal info over the file there is no problem. But, when I run the gdalwarp I had the error. Consequently I believe is a GDAL issues on my OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update to this question.

If you still need to stick to R to process your images, you can use the `gdalUtils` package, which is basically a wrapper to all GDAL applications.

For example, you can use the commands that @Kersten smartly proposed from within R, by using the following script:

```
library(gdalUtils)

gdalbuildvrt("MOD13Q1.*.hdf", "NDVI.vrt", sd=1)

gdalwarp("NDVI.vrt", "NDVI-mosaic.tif",
         t_srs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs", multi=TRUE)
```

These functions will basically call your system's GDAL commands, but through R.

Please note the `multi` argument, which also allows for multithread and, therefore, speeds up your computations a little bit.

Hope this is useful.